# Get dataframe from confusing dictionary data structure

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary like on below :

```
    {1:            ds       yhat  yhat_lower  yhat_upper
30 2015-08-09  49.908927   31.632462   66.742083
31 2015-08-16  49.750056   34.065527   67.069122
32 2015-08-23  49.591185   32.620258   67.403908
33 2015-08-30  49.432314   32.257891   67.541757
34 2015-09-06  72.395618   55.612973   89.711030
35 2015-09-13  49.114572   32.199945   66.255518
36 2015-09-20  48.955701   30.759960   66.118051,
    2:            ds       yhat  yhat_lower  yhat_upper
30 2015-08-09  38.001931   23.583157   51.291784
31 2015-08-16  37.922999   25.370967   50.504328
32 2015-08-23  37.844068   23.743860   51.143868
33 2015-08-30  37.765136   24.903955   50.309284
34 2015-09-06  39.227773   25.089493   52.719935
35 2015-09-13  37.607273   24.370609   51.313454
36 2015-09-20  37.528341   23.395560   50.499454}
```

Want to get dataframe  like this output

```
ProductCode    ds         yhat       yhat_lower  yhat_upper
  1           2015-08-09  49.908927   31.632462   66.742083
  1           2015-08-16  49.750056   34.065527   67.069122
  1           2015-08-23  49.591185   32.620258   67.403908
  1           2015-08-30  49.432314   32.257891   67.541757
  1           2015-09-06  72.395618   55.612973   89.711030
  1           2015-09-13  49.114572   32.199945   66.255518
  1           2015-09-20  48.955701   30.759960   66.118051,
  2           2015-08-09  38.001931   23.583157   51.291784
  2           2015-08-16  37.922999   25.370967   50.504328
  2           2015-08-23  37.844068   23.743860   51.143868
  2           2015-08-30  37.765136   24.903955   50.309284
  2           2015-09-06  39.227773   25.089493   52.719935
  2           2015-09-13  37.607273   24.370609   51.313454
  2           2015-09-20  37.528341   23.395560   50.499454
```

My failed attempt:
 new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.items(), columns=['ProductCode', 'yhat'])
 print(new_df)

```
      ProdutCode    yhat

     0  1        ds yhat yhat_lower yhat_upp...
     1  2        ds yhat yhat_lower yhat_upp...
```

in the dictionary all the ds yhat yhat_lower and yhat_upper head and their values were taken as dict.values(). How to separate those letter part as Dataframe columns and numeric value part is their own column values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us try `pd.concat`

```
yourdf=pd.concat(d).reset_index(level=0)
```